# Escaping [one place] to [another] - sentence structure validity

Tags: prepositions, syntactic-analysis

I want to use the following phrase in this specific structure (if possible):

> How come social media is considered as a way for people to escape life when they sometimes **escape social media to(?) life**!?

But as I didn't find the name of place following "escape" is followed by a preposition in order to mention the other place, I'm wondering if it is correct to structure it like that with the preposition "to".

I'm thinking of another way to form the second part:

> ...when they sometimes use life to escape social media.

I *think* this one is correct, but I'm more interested in the first one.

---

Therefore, what is the correct preposition that can reside between **the place you are escaping from** and **the place you are going to** if it was possible for the sentence to be structured in that way?

Comment: Migrated by the author’s request from ELL.

Comment: I would say that one would often (in British English) use "for". "Escape A for B."  "they sometimes escape social media *for real* life!" Or "... *in favour of real life*.

Comment: @TrevorD _ Thank you for the answer. I would also like to know if the second way of my phrasing of the sentence is correct.

Comment: @TrevorD _ Another thing, does "for" make the suitable preposition for physical/actual places?

Comment: Yes, it does (*During the 19th century, Queen Victoria, Edward VII and the elite of British society escaped London for lavish "weekending" parties at the estate.*). Also, you can just use *escape from X to Y*, as in [*At noon she emerges, **escaping from imagination to the lesser terrors of reality**.*](https://www.thefreelibrary.com/Sofonisba.-a0453920667) (or *...who actively helped Jews escape to England from Nazi Germany*). As for your second sentence, I'd say you normally encounter this pattern in phrases like *use drugs to escape reality*, etc. I guess your sentence makes sense, however.

Comment: @userr2684291 _ Thank you for answering both of my sub-questions.

Comment: I agree with the answers from @TasneemZH. In response to both your Qs, I would emphasize that I would use either "*real life*" or "*reality*" in preference for just "*life*", to make the meaning clear (because "*life*" by itself can have many interpretations).  I'm not entirely sure what you are referring to in your second Q.: yes, *for* is used for physical/actual places - but whether it is appropriate *may* depend both on what *precedes* it, and on the 'type' of place (building, town, road, country, etc.) being referred to.

Comment: @TrevorD _ I have wanted to ask if I should use "real life" in the first part of my main example sentence too (since you did that for the second part), so I guess I should. About the second question, I meant the same structure but with a physical place instead of "real life" (and for "social media" as well to make a logical connection between the two places), for example, _she sometimes escapes her family house for her friend house._ (I think it can be phrased a lot better and make more senes with the standard structure: from ... to

Comment: 1. If I understand your first Q. correctly, yes I would say: "How come social media is considered as a way for people to escape life, [*Note comma inserted*] when they sometimes escape social media **for** [or **in favour of**] **real** life!?"  2. Yes you could say: "she sometimes escapes her family house **in favour of** her friend's house." [Note it should be "**friend's** house" - not "friend house".]